# How to find the nearest point inside the intersection of two circles to any given point on the surface of a sphere

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, quaternions, spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

This drawing I made when I was thinking about the problem shows that my initial idea was simply to calculate the nearest point to the circle whats center point is closest to the target, then from that point (as a new target), calculate the nearest point to the other circle. (The bright green lines shows this).

[problem visualized quite crudely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC7uv.png)

[In this video,](https://youtu.be/9U_xCIqTw2k) in the first half you can see it's working as intended, but in the second half, when the intersection reduces to theoretically a single point, the errors are apparent.

[This other video](https://youtu.be/uSif4s0KEzs) shows (likely) another problem near the poles. It looks very much like gimbal-lock but I'm using quaternions and `slerp` to interpolate these positions, so it shouldn't be. Also, without the limiting factor it places the object to the right place. (But it's not using interpolation then, because it's not needed)

Comment: A general answer using the fact that great circles provide minimal distances. Let $A$ and $B$ be the intersection points of the two circles. Let $M$ be the given point, and $M'$ its opposite point. Consider the family of all **great circles** $C_{\alpha}$ (parametrization to be precised) passing through $M$ and $M'$ that pass in between $A$ and $B$  If $I_{\alpha}$ and $J_{\alpha}$ are the intersection points of $C_{\alpha}$ with the given circles (whose coordinates must be obtained as functions of $\alpha$), the solution is to be found among those points $I_{\alpha}$ and $J_{\alpha}$.

Comment: Which parameterization do you use for your circles ? Besides, do you use spherical coordinates ? Last thing : have you thought to solve your problem by taking the x0y plane as the bissector plane such that $I_{\alpha}$ and $J_{\alpha}$ are symmetrical with respect to this horizontal plane and use back and forth rotations to bring the situation into this context ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea (as far as I understand it from the picture and description) is not correct. For example, by your description and picture, for point 6 your algorithm will find the nearest point as a point that is on the circumference of the bigger circle but not the nearby intersection of the circles, which it should be.

Some nomenclature: $c_1$ is one considered circle, with $M_1, r_1$ being its center and radius. Similiarly, $c_2, M_2, r_2$ for the second circle, center, radius. $A$ and $B$ are the points where $c_1$ and $c_2$ intersect. $P$ is the point whose nearest intersection point we are looking for. Spherical distance between points $X,Y$ is $d(X,Y)$.

My solution would go as follows:

1) Determine if $P$ is inside both circles $c_1$ and $c_2$. If yes, $P$ is inside the intersection and is itself the nearest point, and we are done.

2a) Find the nearest point $N_1$ to $P$ on the whole $c_1$. As commented on by Jean Marie, use the great circle through $M_1$ and $P$ to do that. If $P=M_1$, choose any point $N_1$ on $c_1$.

2b) Do the same as 2a) for circle $c_2$ and find $N_2$.

3a) Determine if $N_1$ is on the arc of $c_1$ that borders your intersection. If yes set $d_1:=d(N_1,P)$, otherwise set $d_1$ equal to $+\infty$.

3b) Do the same as 3a) for $N_2$ and $c_2$, defining the distance $d_2$.

4) Find $d_{min}=\min (d_1, d_2, d(P,A), d(P,B))$

5) Your nearest point is whichever corresponds to the argument that produced the minimum in 4).

Comment: The hardest part was `3a)`. And I'm still not 100% right on that. Right now I'm doing this:
- Since I can only measure the shorter angle between any two vectors, I have to determine if the shorter or the larger arc is the correct one. For this, I check if M1 is between the great circle determined by `A` and `B` and M2. If yes, the larger arc is what makes the intersection.
- I check the angle between M->A and M ->B, (lets name this MA_MB) and then both of them to M->N
- If MA_MB - MA_MN + MB_MN < 0.001 then its ok.
 The problem with this is that these angle calculations are not 100% right.